# How to add headers to a multicolumn listbox in an Excel userform using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to set up the headers in a multicolumn listbox without using a worksheet range as the source?

The following uses an array of variants which is assigned to the list property of the listbox, the headers appear blank.

```
Sub testMultiColumnLb()
    ReDim arr(1 To 3, 1 To 2)

    arr(1, 1) = "1"
    arr(1, 2) = "One"
    arr(2, 1) = "2"
    arr(2, 2) = "Two"
    arr(3, 1) = "3"
    arr(3, 2) = "Three"


    With ufTestUserForm.lbTest
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .List = arr
    End With

    ufTestUserForm.Show 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No.  I create labels above the listbox to serve as headers.  You might think that it's a royal pain to change labels every time your lisbox changes.  You'd be right - it is a pain.  It's a pain to set up the first time, much less changes.  But I haven't found a better way.

Comment: Yes, Dick's answer is the right way to go if your listbox only has a few columns, say 5 or less.

Comment: The solution of using labels is of no use if your list box scrolls. 11 years on and Microsoft still can't update Excel in 2020 to be useful, every version VBA can be seen as just more dreadful than the last year.

Answer (score 21):

### Here is my approach to solve the problem:

This solution requires you to add a second ListBox element and place it above the first one.

Like this:

[image: Add an additional ListBox]

Then you call the function CreateListBoxHeader  to make the alignment correct and add header items.

**Result:**

[image: Call the function CreateListBoxHeader]

### Code:

```
  Public Sub CreateListBoxHeader(body As MSForms.ListBox, header As MSForms.ListBox, arrHeaders)
            ' make column count match
            header.ColumnCount = body.ColumnCount
            header.ColumnWidths = body.ColumnWidths

        ' add header elements
        header.Clear
        header.AddItem
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To UBound(arrHeaders)
            header.List(0, i) = arrHeaders(i)
        Next i

        ' make it pretty
        body.ZOrder (1)
        header.ZOrder (0)
        header.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
        header.BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        header.Height = 10

        ' align header to body (should be done last!)
        header.Width = body.Width
        header.Left = body.Left
        header.Top = body.Top - (header.Height - 1)
End Sub
```

### Usage:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Call CreateListBoxHeader(Me.listBox_Body, Me.listBox_Header, Array("Header 1", "Header 2"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You. I like this method. I have a list box that is wider than width of the form. Therefore, The user must scroll horizontally to view additional columns. The header listbox does not scroll with the data listbox. Do you have any solutions for this situation?

Comment: I know this is old but I had to tweak the code slightly for a header array created from an Excel range.

`For i = LBound(arrHeaders) To UBound(arrHeaders) ' Changed to use LBound
    header.List(0, i - 1) = arrHeaders(i) ' Changed to i - 1`

Comment: I do not know why the other answer that came after is the accepted one. This one is much cleaner and easier, for any # of columns. I would only add `header.Locked=True`, to avoid user messing with it.

Comment: Do we have any update on this if the header listbox can be also move when the data listbox move?

Answer (score 9):

I was looking at this problem just now and found this solution. If your **RowSource** points to a range of cells, the column headings in a multi-column listbox are taken from the cells immediately above the RowSource.

Using the example pictured here, inside the listbox, the words **Symbol** and **Name** appear as title headings. When I changed the word Name in cell AB1, then opened the form in the VBE again, the column headings changed.

[image: Screenshot displaying a named range and the column headings outside the range.]

The example came from a workbook in VBA For Modelers by S. Christian Albright, and I was trying to figure out how he got the column headings in his listbox :)

Comment: Oh right, you didn't want a worksheet range as a source. Oh well, I hope people find it interesting. Surprised it took me a year to notice this.

Comment: So useful. Thank you for sharing. Using your suggestion makes creating multi-column list boxes so much easier

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer: no.

What I've done in the past is load the headings into row 0 then set the ListIndex to 0 when displaying the form.  This then highlights the "headings" in blue, giving the appearance of a header.  The form action buttons are ignored if the ListIndex remains at zero, so these values can never be selected.

Of course, as soon as another list item is selected, the heading loses focus, but by this time their job is done.

Doing things this way also allows you to have headings that scroll horizontally, which is difficult/impossible to do with separate labels that float above the listbox.  The flipside is that the headings do not remain visible if the listbox needs to scroll vertically.

Basically, it's a compromise that works in the situations I've been in.

Comment: How about creating another ListBox, immediately above the "real" ListBox. This would have only 1 row to contain the headers, and then scroll them simultaneously. I haven't tried it, but think it can be done, no?

Comment: Unfortunately ListBox don't have "Scrolled" event.
But one can instead create wide enough ListBox and place Labels above it as column headers. Then place it all inside of a Frame to scroll the Frame together with Labels and Listbox horizontally.

Answer (score 4):

There is very easy solution to show headers at the top of multi columns list box.
Just change the property value to "true" for "columnheads" which is false by default.

After that Just mention the data range in property "rowsource" excluding header from the data range and header should be at first top row of data range then it will pick the header automatically and you header will be freezed.

**if suppose you have data in range "A1:H100" and header at "A1:H1" which is the first row then your data range should be "A2:H100" which needs to mention in property "rowsource" and "columnheads" perperty value should be true**

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: You missed the bit where the OP wanted to do it _without using a worksheet range as the source_.

Answer (score 4):

Just use two Listboxes, one for header and other for data

1. for headers - set RowSource property to top row e.g. Incidents!Q4:S4
2. for data  - set Row Source Property to Incidents!Q5:S10

SpecialEffects to "3-frmSpecialEffectsEtched"
[image]

Comment: This works far better than anything else mentioned here so far. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the following approach for headers on a ComboBox where the CboBx is not loaded from a worksheet (data from sql for example).  The reason I specify not from a worksheet is that I think the only way to get RowSource to work is if you load from a worksheet.

This works for me:

1. Create your ComboBox and create a ListBox with an identical layout but just one row.
2. Place the ListBox directly on top of the ComboBox.
3. In your VBA, load ListBox row1 with the desired headers.
4. In your VBA for the action yourListBoxName_Click, enter the following code:

   ```
   yourComboBoxName.Activate`
   yourComboBoxName.DropDown`
   ```
5. When you click on the listbox, the combobox will drop down and function normally while the headings (in the listbox) remain above the list.

Comment: Very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for quite a while for a solution to add a header without using a separate sheet and copy everything into the userform.

My solution is to use the first row as header and run it through an if condition and add additional items underneath.

Like that:

```html
If lborowcount = 0 Then
 With lboorder
 .ColumnCount = 5
 .AddItem
 .Column(0, lborowcount) = "Item"
 .Column(1, lborowcount) = "Description"
 .Column(2, lborowcount) = "Ordered"
 .Column(3, lborowcount) = "Rate"
 .Column(4, lborowcount) = "Amount"
 End With
 lborowcount = lborowcount + 1
End If
        
        
With lboorder
 .ColumnCount = 5
 .AddItem
 .Column(0, lborowcount) = itemselected
 .Column(1, lborowcount) = descriptionselected
 .Column(2, lborowcount) = orderedselected
 .Column(3, lborowcount) = rateselected
 .Column(4, lborowcount) = amountselected
 
 
 End With

lborowcount = lborowcount + 1
```

in that example lboorder is the listbox, lborowcount counts at which row to add the next listbox item. It's a 5 column listbox. Not ideal but it works and when you have to scroll horizontally the "header" stays above the row.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

I noticed that when I specify the listbox's rowsource via the properties window in the VBE, the headers pop up no problem. Its only when we try define the rowsource through VBA code that the headers get lost.

So I first went a defined the listboxes rowsource as a named range in the VBE for via the properties window, then I can reset the rowsource in VBA code after that. The headers still show up every time.

I am using this in combination with an advanced filter macro from a listobject, which then creates another (filtered) listobject on which the rowsource is based.

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Another variant on Lunatik's response is to use a local boolean and the change event so that the row can be highlighted upon initializing, but deselected and blocked after a selection change is made by the user:

```
Private Sub lbx_Change()

    If Not bHighlight Then

        If Me.lbx.Selected(0) Then Me.lbx.Selected(0) = False

    End If

    bHighlight = False

End Sub
```

When the listbox is initialized you then set bHighlight and lbx.Selected(0) = True, which will allow the header-row to initialize selected; afterwards, the first change will deselect and prevent the row from being selected again...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach which automates creating labels above each column of a listbox (on a worksheet).

It will work (though not super-pretty!) as long as there's no horizontal scrollbar on your listbox.

```
Sub Tester()
Dim i As Long

With Me.lbTest
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 5
    'must do this next step!
    .ColumnWidths = "70;60;100;60;60"
    .ListStyle = fmListStylePlain
    Debug.Print .ColumnWidths
    For i = 0 To 10
        .AddItem
        .List(i, 0) = "blah" & i
        .List(i, 1) = "blah"
        .List(i, 2) = "blah"
        .List(i, 3) = "blah"
        .List(i, 4) = "blah"
    Next i

End With

LabelHeaders Me.lbTest, Array("Header1", "Header2", _
                     "Header3", "Header4", "Header5")

End Sub

Sub LabelHeaders(lb, arrHeaders)

    Const LBL_HT As Long = 15
    Dim T, L, shp As Shape, cw As String, arr
    Dim i As Long, w

    'delete any previous headers for this listbox
    For i = lb.Parent.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
        If lb.Parent.Shapes(i).Name Like lb.Name & "_*" Then
            lb.Parent.Shapes(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i

    'get an array of column widths
    cw = lb.ColumnWidths
    If Len(cw) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    cw = Replace(cw, " pt", "")
    arr = Split(cw, ";")

    'start points for labels
    T = lb.Top - LBL_HT
    L = lb.Left

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        w = CLng(arr(i))
        If i = UBound(arr) And (L + w) < lb.Width Then w = lb.Width - L
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, _
                                         L, T, w, LBL_HT)
        With shp
            .Name = lb.Name & "_" & i
            'do some formatting
            .Line.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
            .Line.Weight = 1
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(220, 220, 220)
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = arrHeaders(i)
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 9
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
        End With
        L = L + w
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Not compatible with Office 2007, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a try. I am quite new to the forum but wanted to offer something that worked for me since I've gotten so much help from this site in the past. This is essentially a variation of the above, but I found it simpler.

Just paste this into the Userform_Initialize section of your userform code. Note you must already have a listbox on the userform or have it created dynamically above this code. Also please note the Array is a list of headings (below as "Header1", "Header2" etc. Replace these with your own headings. This code will then set up a heading bar at the top based on the column widths of the list box. Sorry it doesn't scroll - it's fixed labels.

More senior coders - please feel free to comment or improve this.

```
    Dim Mywidths As String
    Dim Arrwidths, Arrheaders As Variant
    Dim ColCounter, Labelleft As Long
    Dim theLabel As Object                

    [Other code here that you would already have in the Userform_Initialize section]

    Set theLabel = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test" & ColCounter, True)
            With theLabel
                    .Left = ListBox1.Left
                    .Top = ListBox1.Top - 10
                    .Width = ListBox1.Width - 1
                    .Height = 10
                    .BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
            End With
            Arrheaders = Array("Header1", "Header2", "Header3", "Header4")

            Mywidths = Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths
            Mywidths = Replace(Mywidths, " pt", "")
            Arrwidths = Split(Mywidths, ";")
            Labelleft = ListBox1.Left + 18
            For ColCounter = LBound(Arrwidths) To UBound(Arrwidths)
                        If Arrwidths(ColCounter) > 0 Then
                                Header = Header + 1
                                Set theLabel = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "Test" & ColCounter, True)

                                With theLabel
                                    .Caption = Arrheaders(Header - 1)
                                    .Left = Labelleft
                                    .Width = Arrwidths(ColCounter)
                                    .Height = 10
                                    .Top = ListBox1.Top - 10
                                    .BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
                                    .Font.Bold = True
                                End With
                                 Labelleft = Labelleft + Arrwidths(ColCounter)

                        End If
             Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bummer. Have to use an intermediate sheet to put the data in so Excel knows to grab the headers. But I wanted that workbook to be hidden so here's how I had to do the rowsource.
Most of this code is just setting things up...

```
Sub listHeaderTest()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim testarr() As String
Dim numberOfRows As Long
Dim x As Long, n As Long

'example sheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
'example headers
For x = 1 To UserForm1.ListBox1.ColumnCount
    ws.Cells(1, x) = "header" & x
Next x
'example array dimensions
numberOfRows = 15
ReDim testarr(numberOfRows, UserForm1.ListBox1.ColumnCount - 1)
'example values for the array/listbox
For n = 0 To UBound(testarr)
    For x = 0 To UBound(testarr, 2)
        testarr(n, x) = "test" & n & x
    Next x
Next n

'put array data into the worksheet
ws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(testarr), UBound(testarr, 2) + 1) = testarr

'provide rowsource
UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = "'[" & ws.Parent.Name & "]" & ws.Name & "'!" _
& ws.Range("A2").Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Address

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For scrolling, one idea is to create a simulated scroll bar which would shift the entire listbox left and right.

1. ensure the list box is set to full width so the horizontal scroll
   bar doesn't appear (wider than the space available, or we wouldn't
   need to scroll)
2. add a scroll bar control at the bottom but with .left and .width to
   match the available horizontal space (so not as wide as the too-wide listbox)
3. calculate the distance you need to scroll as the difference between
   the width of the extended list box and the width of the available
   horizontal space
4. set .Min to 0 and .Max to the amount you need to scroll
5. set .LargeChange to make the slider-bar wider (I could only get it
   to be half of the total span)

For this to work, you'd need to be able to cover left and right of the intended viewing space with a frame so that the listbox can pass underneath it and preserve any horizontal framing in the form.  This turn out to be challenging, as getting a frame to cover a listbox seems not to work easily.  I gave up at that point but am sharing these steps for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that seems to work but it can get messy the more complicated your code gets if you're dynamically clearing the range after every search or changing range.

Spreadsheet:

```
A    B       C  

1   LName    Fname 

2   Smith    Bob
```

---

```vb
set rng_Name = ws_Name.range("A1", ws_Name.range("C2").value 
    
lstbx.Main.rowsource = rng_Name.Address
```

This will loads the Headers into the listbox and allow you to scroll.

Most importantly, if you're looping through your data and your range comes up empty, then your listbox won't load the headers correctly, so you will have to account for no "matches".

Answer (score 0):

Can do like given below...

```
Sub testMultiColumnLb()
   ReDim arr(0 To 3, 0 To 2)

   'Header Row
   arr(0, 1) = "Number"
   arr(0, 2) = "Number in Text"

   'Content Rows
   arr(1, 1) = "1"
   arr(1, 2) = "One"
   arr(2, 1) = "2"
   arr(2, 2) = "Two"
   arr(3, 1) = "3"
   arr(3, 2) = "Three"


   With ufTestUserForm.lbTest
     .Clear
     .ColumnCount = 2
     .List = arr
   End With

   ufTestUserForm.Show 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

Why not just add Labels to the top of the Listbox and if changes are needed, the only thing you need to programmatically change are the labels.

Comment: The question specifically asked how to do it with VBA.