# How to add text to column headers in list box with multiple columns?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to fetch some data from database and then display it on a list box that have multiple columns. Is this possible to assign some meaningful text to the column headers? Right now, these column header appears empty.

**I have more than 15 columns and moreover, it's dynamic that means depending on search result, number of columns may change.**  [Not Implemented Yet]

Using Label as column header for this scenario doesn't seems to me a better solution. Is there any other way?

My code is as follows:

```
Dim conn As New Connection
Dim rs As New Recordset

strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data Source=C:\Users\raj.kamal\Desktop\ActionWord.accdb;" & _
"User Id=;Password="

conn.Open (strcon)
InputSearchText = SearchTxtBox.Text
qry = "SELECT * FROM ActionWordTable where ActionWordName like" & "'%" & InputSearchText & "%'"
rs.Open qry, conn, adOpenKeyset
rs.MoveFirst
i = 0
With Me.SearchResultListBox
.Clear
.ColumnCount = 7
.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
Do
.AddItem
.List(i, 0) = rs![ActionWordName]
.List(i, 1) = rs![Parameter1]
.List(i, 2) = rs![Parameter2]
.List(i, 3) = rs![Parameter3]
.List(i, 4) = rs![Parameter4]
.List(i, 5) = rs![Parameter5]
.List(i, 6) = rs![Parameter6]
i = i + 1
rs.MoveNext
Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
rs.Close
conn.Close


End Sub
```

and the result looks like:[image]

Comment: I have checked this solution [How to add headers to a multicolumn listbox in an Excel userform using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657498/how-to-add-headers-to-a-multicolumn-listbox-in-an-excel-userform-using-vba)  but it doesn't seems to fit in my scenario. I have edited my questions for more clear understanding. @tim

Comment: The question I linked to was the same as yours (is there any way to populate the listbox headers without filling the listbox from a range?). The answer is no, there is not, and a few people suggested workarounds.  One thing you might try is dumping your recordset data to a worksheet (with headers) rather than load it directly into the listbox.

Comment: Good Idea @TimWilliams. I can try this.

Comment: OK - I also just posted another answer at the "duplicate" question.