# Editing column headers in userform listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, columnheader

I have a listbox I want to add column headers to.  The `.ColumnHeads` property provides a row for headers, but I can't provide labels for each column individually.  I'm not using a cell range for the source since the header needs to be dynamic.

Another possible solution would just be to disable selection of the 1st row in the listbox.  I tried the technique by ChE Junkie [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657498/how-to-add-headers-to-a-multicolumn-listbox-in-an-excel-userform-using-vba) but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've messed with this a couple of times and just remember it's far more difficult than it's worth.  In the end I always just put a label above each column.