# Why does Excel freeze after Resizing a Table/ListObject which is used as a RowSource for a ListBox?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, listobject

The following example is a realiable way to crash excel 2010.

1. Insert Userform with ListBox
2. Insert a Table into the same Workbook
3. Set the 'RowSource' Property of the ListBox to 'TableName'
4. Resize the Table

The resizing causes a freeze, excel will then try to restart but usually doesn't manage to do it. The only way to get out is to x-out the restart menu or restart your computer. You will certainly loose all unsaved progress so please don't do this when working on something.

- Why does this happen?
- How to avoid it/ solve it?

Edit 1: It comes even better! [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657498/how-to-add-headers-to-a-multicolumn-listbox-in-an-excel-userform-using-vba) states that there is no other way than RowSource to get titles for your MultiColumn Listbox (unless you do it yourself with lables). So either leave a potentially lethal bug in the code or do all headers with your own code..

Comment: Disclaimer: There is one very obvious way of avoiding it. You simple don't do it.  You just set 'RowSource' of the ListBox to an empty string before you want to resize the Listobject.

Comment: Or preferably don't bind controls directly to ranges at all.

Comment: @Rory I suspected that this would be the conclusion of this question. My answer until now is : This does happen, so don't do it.

Answer (score -1):

If the resizing table causes rowsource to crash, then avoid it before resizing it.

```
listbox1.rowsource = ""
```

do your things

```
listbox1.rowsource = "your range"
```