# Update ListBox RowSoure at runtime

Tags: excel, vba

I am building an Excel workbook with a userform built with vba.  I have a listbox control on it with multiple columns.  I want the column headers to appear.  So from what I read, I am forced to populate the listbox using the RowSource property.  I tied the RowSource to a listobject.  The userform also has buttons to add or remove rows in the listobject, which need to be repeated in the listbox.  When I try to update the RowSource after a change in the listbox, Excel crashes and reopens every time.

I have a solution to work around this problem.  If I populate the listbox using the List property, I can add and remove rows and everything works fine.  But if I do use the List property, it is not possible to have column headers in the listbox.  There is a solution for this too as suggested by Jonas_Hess in this post: [How to add headers to a multicolumn listbox in an Excel userform using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657498/how-to-add-headers-to-a-multicolumn-listbox-in-an-excel-userform-using-vba).  But I would of prefered to have the column headers in the listbox itself.

To reproduce the problem I built a simple form with a listbox and a button.  I tied the RowSource of the listbox to a listobject.  The listobject only has three rows and 1 column. The cell values are 1, 2, 3.   The button's purpose is to add new rows to the listobject and update the listbox.

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ListBox1.RowSource = Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Address
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim Table As ListObject

    Set Table = Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1)
    Table.Resize Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Table.ListRows.Count + 2, 1))
    Table.DataBodyRange(Table.ListRows.Count, 1).Value =  Table.DataBodyRange(Table.ListRows.Count - 1, 1).Value + 1
    ListBox1.RowSource = Empty
    ListBox1.RowSource = Table.DataBodyRange.Address
End Sub
```

I am wondering if there is a way to add or delete rows of the RowSource property of a listbox in Excel VBA.

Comment: The `ListBox RowSource Property` does not have any `Methods`, so you cannot add or remove rows directly from the `RowSource Property`. 
What you can do, is add or remove rows from a `Range` and assign that `Range` to the `RowSource Property`.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing.  But every time I reassign the RowSource to the new Range, which is a ListObject in my case, Excel crashes.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with F8 to see where it crashes?  I'll try replicating the problem right now and see what happens for me.

Comment: Could not replicate.  Created `UserForm1` with a `ListBox` and a `CommandButton` and pasted your code into `UserForm1`.  The only thing I changed was a subname for `CommandButton1_Click`.  My table on `Sheet1` is A1:A4, the `DataBodyRange` is A2:A4, values are 1,2,3.  My `ListBox` has `HeaderColumns` set to `True` and `RowSource` is blank.  I have a button on my worksheet to call a sub that instantiates and shows the form: `If frm Is Nothing Then Set frm = New UserForm1` and then `frm.Show`.  Clicking the `CommandButton` on the form adds a row to the  `Table` and `ListBox`..

Comment: I retested by setting the `RowSource` directly in the VBA editor to A2:A4 and also A1:A4 without receiving an error.  Not sure what I am doing that is different from you.  Using Office 365 Pro Plus on Win10 64bit.  I can suggest rebooting and putting a breakpoint on `Set Table = Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1)` and then using F8 to advance through the code to determine where the crash is occuring.

Comment: Thank you ProfoundlyOblivious for looking into this.  From the explanations you gave, I understand you are doing exactly what would make my Excel crash.  I am using Excel 2019 32 bits on Win10 64 bits.  I just rebooted and it still has the same behaviour.  Going step-by-step, Excel crashes at the `ListBox1.RowSource = Empty` line.  I also tried setting the RowSource to A2:A4 and it also crashed.  Since you are not seeing the same problem, it seems it might be related to my Excel version.  I will try to get Excel 2019 64 bits installed and give it a try and also test on a colleagues workstation

Answer (score 0):

Following ProfoundlyOblivious suggestions, I tried the same code on a colleagues workstation.  He has Excel 2016 32 bits on Windows 10 64 bits.  Turns out Excel was crashing at the `Table.Resize` line for him.  This gave me the idea to try and reassign the `ListBox1.RowSource = Empty` prior to messing to the `ListObject`.  Everything worked fine.  Excel did not crash when reassigning the `RowSource`, on both workstations.

Here's the modified code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ListBox1.RowSource = Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Address
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
    Dim Table As ListObject

    ListBox1.RowSource = Empty
    Set Table = Worksheets(Feuil1.Index).ListObjects(1)
    Table.Resize Worksheets(Feuil1.Index).Range(Worksheets(Feuil1.Index).Cells(1, 1), Worksheets(Feuil1.Index).Cells(Table.ListRows.Count + 2, 1))
    Table.DataBodyRange(Table.ListRows.Count, 1).Value = Table.DataBodyRange(Table.ListRows.Count - 1, 1).Value + 1
    ListBox1.RowSource = Table.DataBodyRange.Address
End Sub
```

I have cell A1 = Number, A2 = 1, A3 = 2, A4 = 3.  Clicking the add button added a new value below the usedrange and in the `ListBox`.
It looks like using the `ListObject.Resize` method when it is linked to a `RowSource`is not stable on all Excel versions and was the source of my problem.