# How to dynamically create an element's position?

Tags: vba, outlook, listbox, userform

I have an Outlook userform to show selected emails.
Since listboxes cannot have text in the column-headers, I adapted the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657498/how-to-add-headers-to-a-multicolumn-listbox-in-an-excel-userform-using-vba).

**My Problem:**

After intialization of the form, the header-box is at a wrong position and with a wrong size. Some checks show, that the correct values are allocated by the function createListboxHeader() - and without error. But checking the header-box's position and size after that function (back in initialization), the values are wrong - prove of what I see.

Sometimes it works correctly, but most of the times not.

**Code:**

```
Public Sub createListboxHeader(lstBody As ListBox, arrHeaders)
Dim lstHeader As ListBox
Dim i As Integer

'create new listbox for the header
Set lstHeader = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1","NameOnlyForTesting")

With lstBody
    'ensure properties of body-listbox
    .ColumnHeads = False
    .ZOrder (1)
    .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
    .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
End With

With lstHeader
    'properties of header-listbox
    .BackColor = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    .Enabled = False
    .ZOrder (0)
    .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
    .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle

    'make column equal
    .ColumnCount = lstBody.ColumnCount
    .ColumnWidths = lstBody.ColumnWidths

    'add header elements
    .AddItem
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrHeaders)
        .List(0, i) = arrHeaders(i)
    Next i

    'positioning of header-listbox
    .Height = 10
    .Width = lstBody.Width
    .Left = lstBody.Left
    .Top = (lstBody.Top - lstHeader.Height) - 0

    Debug.Print lstBody.Width, lstHeader.Height     ' <-- show both '400'
End With

End Sub
```

**Usage:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'find emails
Dim selEmails As Outlook.Selection
Set selEmails = getSelectedEmails() 'function not displayed here at StackOverflow

'show emails in List-Box
Call printSelectedEmailsInList(selEmails)

End Sub


Private Sub printSelectedEmailsInList(selectedEmails As Outlook.Selection)
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim intCounter  As Integer
Dim arrHeaders() As Variant

With Me.lstSelectedEmails
    'configure listbox
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 5
    .ColumnWidths = "70;100;100;200;100"

    'configute header (AFTER body!)
    arrHeaders = Array("Date", "From", "To", "Subject", "Folder")
    Call createListboxHeader(Me.lstSelectedEmails, arrHeaders)
    MsgBox Me.Controls("NameOnlyForTesting").Width             '<-- shows'78' instead of '400'

    'fill list with emails
    intCounter = 0
    For Each objEmail In selectedEmails
        .AddItem
        .List(intCounter, 0) = objEmail.SentOn
        .List(intCounter, 1) = objEmail.SenderName
        .List(intCounter, 2) = objEmail.To
        .List(intCounter, 3) = objEmail.Subject
        .List(intCounter, 4) = objEmail.Parent.Name

        intCounter = intCounter + 1
    Next

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Listboxes cant have column headers? What's the `.ColumnHeads` property for then? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.listbox.columnheads

Comment: Hello braX, the property `.ColumnHeads` activates an addtional row for headers. That's true. But you cannot put any text in these fields. This works only if you use `.RowSource` in parallel. But not if you create the content dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, by changing:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   [...]
End Sub
```

to:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
   [...]
End Sub
```