# Change Style of ListBox

Tags: vba, outlook, listbox

In Outlook 2010 I have a UserForm with a ListBox.
This ListBox has 4 columns where I show a list of attachments (the columns "File-Name", "File-Type", "File-Size" and "Target-Directory".

Unfortunately the ListBox is restricted in layout functionality, the user can not adjust the column width at runtime (so I have to specify the width of the columns by design).
Because the file path can be quiet long, I set the width of the last column to 999 Pt.

So my ListBox has a **horizontal scrollbar**.

I want to have the following layout changes to my ListBox:

1. Add column headers
2. Change the alignment of a column to right-aligned
3. Optional: allow the user to sort the list by any column
4. Optional: allow the user to sort change the width of any column
5. Optional: show a grid in the ListBox

For 1. I found some answers that this is very complicated and I should use static labels above the list instead.
This is not possible, because my ListBox can be scrolled horizontally.

Is the ListBox really so restricted or is #1 and #2 possible somehow?

I know that there are foreign components available, but I am not allowed to buy any component.

And my solution should work at my colleagues too, so they would also have to install these components.

Answer (score 1):

I have been experimenting with possible solutions to your problem.  I think I have taken the listbox approach as far as it will go so I will share what I have discovered.

I can find nothing on the web to suggest that anyone believes you can have listbox column headers without using property RowSource.  To use RowSource, you set it to an Excel range.

I got Outlook to create an Excel workbook and to write some data to it.  Unfortunately, I could not find any way of getting an Outlook user form to access an Excel range.  The syntax for setting RowSource is:

```
ListBox1.RowSource = "Emails!A2:D20"
```

This is not the standard syntax for a range and I have failed to discover any method of extending it to include a workbook name.

Jonah_Hess describes an interesting approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43381634/973283.   He has two list boxes.  One is a one-line listbox that contains the headings and the other contains the data.  The two listboxes are set to the same number of columns with the same widths.  This gives an attractive appearance but if you scroll the data listbox, the headings listbox does not scroll with it.  This is not really any different from placing labels above a single listbox.

I tried putting the headings and the data list boxes in a frame and scrolling the frame but could not get it to work.  I have used frames with VB user forms but the functionality is very different so there are no lessons learnt that I could bring to a VBA user form.  Perhaps someone more familiar with VBA frames could get this approach to work.

I gave up trying to get a solution in Outlook.  An Excel macro can access Outlook data so I tried that approach.

I created a macro-enabled workbook.  Within it, I have two forms both of which fill the screen to conceal the worksheet.  The first form just says: “Please wait while I load data from Outlook”.  I am not clear about the data on your form so I imported selected details from a folder full of junk emails which I wrote to a worksheet.  I sized the columns for the list box to match those for the worksheet.  The result was:

[image: Scrollable listbox with column headings]

The text is a little small but I think it is readable.  The listbox at the bottom allows me to select emails for different periods.  Long ago I had problems with RowSource which meant I could change the values in the range but I could not change the size of the range.  I have either managed to avoid that problem today or it was a bug that has been fixed.

You can see that the headings are displayed.  The columns are a little wide but I consider them to be a reasonable first approximation.  Options to change the widths would be easy to implement.

The changes you ask for:

- Add column headers.  Done
- Change the alignment of a column to right-aligned.  Possible but difficult.  You would need to pad the text with an appropriate number of leading spaces.
- Optional: allow the user to sort the list by any column.  The data is in a worksheet so easy.
- Optional: allow the user to change the width of any column.  I have set the column widths at runtime to show it is possible.
- Optional: show a grid in the ListBox.  Not possible.

If the above is interesting, I could show you all my code and instruct you on creating the forms so you could duplicate my experiment.  Alternately, I could just explain: how I imported the Outlook data to Excel, how I included the column headings and how I set the column widths.

I cannot find anything to suggest that anything better can be achieved with listboxes.

An alternative approach is to use a grid of labels.  This can give an attractive appearance and one or more columns could be right-aligned.  Using the Controls property of the user form, you can treat the grid as a two-dimensional array.  I have used this technique long ago and found it attractive and not particularly difficult.

Comment: Thank you @Tony-Dallimore for your detailed investigation.
With my VBA my colleagues and I can reduce the size of our Outlook mailboxes. We search for large emails, the VBA shows all attachments of the current email in the ListBox. Here you can select multiple attachments, select the target folder and remove the attachments (the VBA attaches an HTML containing a list of removed files).
So here I need my VBA and UserForm in Outlook, I think Excel does not help here. Working with a grid of labels is also not helping because you can select multiple attachments and assign the target folder.

Comment: @OLLI_S  An Excel macro can access Outlook emails, as my macro demonstrates, so the user form does not have to be in Outlook.  The only downside is that the user would have to give permission for the macro to amend emails every 10 minutes.  The upsides to an Excel macro are that it could be run automatically from the Start event and you avoid the difficulty of distributing Outlook macros.

Comment: I talked with my colleagues about your solution, but we want to stay inside Outlook. Our team writes reports about applications that we inspect and each colleague has an individual folder structure in Outlook. We want to remove the attachments of mails that are in any folder (not just in the inbox). And Outlook has very powerful search mechanisms (search for large mails in all folders). So we decided to stay in Outlook and live with a bad listbox. Thank you for your Excel-Macro, @Tony-Dallimore I will keep it as backup.

Comment: @OLLI_S  Excel VBA can access most of Outlook’s functionality.  I am sure that having a single workbook in a shared folder with a parameter file in a private folder on each user’s would be easier to manage than trying to port Outlook code to each user’s computer.  I described my Excel macro but did not post it because it contains user forms which I cannot post.  If you would like a copy of my workbook, there is an email address in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the alignment of a specific column to the right, trying the opposite way might help you:

1. Set TextAlign attribute of the listbox to "3-fmTextAlignRight".
2. Add spaces at the END of the each data in the column of sourcearray, which you want to align LEFT. The number of added spaces should be so large as to exceed the width of the column in which the data appears. You don't have to mind whether the number fits to the columnwidth (overflown spaces do no harm). You may prefer to use `& String(30, " ")` instead (30 is just for example) .
3. If added spaces seem to be wholly ignored (i.e. data appear right-aligned only), further add any single character (such as "_") at the end of the spaces.

This is a cosmetic solution, but works when seeing left-aligned figures is too annoying.
After doing the above, please be careful when selecting from the list (trimming the added spaces, keeping BoundColumn data intact, etc.).

This trick works for both Excel and Outlook (not sure for other applications).
[Test result in Outlook VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk18Y.png) (...trailing 50 spaces are added to data in column 1 and 4.)

Hope this helps.