# Transposing Values In a Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, transpose

Good day,

I am trying to transpose the values added to my listbox via a query. Also does anyone have tips on how to get the column names on the Column Header. This is what the values in my listbox looks like:

[image: Listbox]

Below is my code thus far:

```
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim reCs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim tarSheet As Worksheet
    Dim strbooK As String, strTar As String
    Dim arTar As Range
    
    strbooK = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Excel_VBA.xlsm"

    
    If opTar.Value = True Then
 
        strTar = "SELECT TargetNumber as [Target Number] " & _
                 ",TargetName as [Target Name] " & _
                 ",TargetPrefix as [Target Nickname] " & _
                 ",Count(TargetNumber) as [Number of Events] " & _
                 "FROM [Master$] " & _
                 "GROUP BY TargetNumber, TargetName, TargetPrefix " & _
                 "HAVING TargetNumber = '" & txt_search.Value & "';"
                 
         Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
                    conn.ConnectionString = _
                    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & strbooK & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
                    
                    conn.Open
                    
                    Set reCs = New ADODB.Recordset
                    reCs.ActiveConnection = conn
                    reCs.Source = strTar
                    reCs.Open

        With lbx_reCs
            .BoundColumn = 1
            .ColumnCount = 4
            .ColumnHeads = True
            .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
            .ColumnWidths = "136;136;136;136;"
            .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
'            .RowSource = arTar.Address
            .List() = reCs.GetRows
        End With

'Releasing Objects
              reCs.Close
              conn.Close
        
    End If
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the titel you need no transpose of the values of the recordset, just use the column property of the listbox.

```
.Column = reCs.GetRows
```

For the other question you might look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657498/how-to-add-headers-to-a-multicolumn-listbox-in-an-excel-userform-using-vba). That seems not to be possible in case you have an array like in this case. On the other hand you also might want to look at this [solution approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60330767/6600940) in the above mentioned post.

Comment: I am getting a runtime error 13 (Type Mismatch) with the .Column = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(reCs.GetRows). Any suggestions please

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my posting. The transpose is not needed with the `.Column` property of the listbox.